# Comparing two p-value distributions and obtaining aggregate significance and effect size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value

## PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

My data is a population of entities. Each entity is a convex set with a border and an interior, which in turn contain two types of cells. For illustrative purposes, let's say I have green and red balls which can be positioned in the border or interior of a given entity. Each entity can be characterized by the numbers:

-$N$: total number of balls 
-$G$: number of green balls
-$R$: number of red balls
-$B$: number of balls at the border
-$I$: number of balls in the interior
-$R_B$: number of red balls at the border
-$R_I$: number of red balls in the interior

These numbers satisfy: $N=I+B=R+G$. I want to test if the data indicate whether there is a tendency of red balls to be at the border.

The example entity below has $N=25, G=11, R=14, B=13, I=12, R_B=8, R_I=6$.

[image: entity]

## NULL DISTRIBUTION AND P-VALUE

In general, the border and interior each have a Bernoulli proportion of their balls being red. If there is no relation between colour and placement at the border, then these two proportions are the same, providing us with the null hypothesis

$$H_0:\text{ proportion of balls red at the border = proportion of balls red in the interior}=\pi$$

Under $H_0$, the conditional probability of having $k$ red border balls given that there are $R$ red balls in total is

$$P(R_B=k \mid R_B+R_I=R)=\frac{\binom{B}{k} \pi^k (1-\pi)^{B-k}\binom{N-B}{R - k}\pi^{R-k} (1-\pi)^{N-B-R+k}}{\binom{N}{R}\pi^R (1-\pi)^{N-R}}=\frac{\binom{B}{k} \binom{N-B}{R - k}}{\binom{N}{R}}, $$

where $R_B,R_I$ are now random variables and $N,B,R$ are fixed.

If red balls prefer the border, then the above hypergeometric distribution should give a small probability for values that are at least as extreme as the observed $R_B$. We use the p-value

$$p=\sum_{k\ge\tilde{R}_B} P(R_B=k \mid R_B+R_I=R),$$

where $\tilde{R}_B$ is the observed value.

## P-VALUE DISTRIBUTION

Note that the above is for a single entity, so if there are $n$ entities, this will result in $n$ p-values. If the null distribution were continuous and identical for all entities, then the distribution of p-values under $H_0$ should be uniform. Then, under $H_0$, $\alpha$% of p-values should be below $\alpha$. If there is more than $\alpha$% below $\alpha$, then this would indicate that red balls prefer the border more than in the random (uncorrelated) case.

However, we have a discrete probability distribution and each entity has a different null distribution due to differing $N,B,R$. So instead of assuming a uniform p-value distribution, we first need to construct a reference p-value distribution that is to be expected under the null hypothesis. We did this by drawing a realisation of $R_B$ from the above hypergeometric distribution for each entity (i.e. for each of the $N,B,R$ in the data).

So now we have *two* p-value distributions, one based on the observed $R_B$ and the other based on a randomly drawn $R_B$. Comparing these should then give an indication of the strength of the tendency of red balls to be at the border.

[image: Observed vs random p-values]

## COMPARING OBSERVED AND RANDOM P-VALUE DISTRIBUTIONS

One way of doing this is with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. However, we are only interested in the left tail of the p-value distribution. More precisely, for a given significance level $\alpha$, we want to know the proportion of p-values below $\alpha$. Therefore, we can use the test statistic

$$D=F_o(\alpha)-F_r(\alpha),$$

where $F_o,F_r$ are the empirical distribution functions of the observed and random p-value distributions. Positive values mean that red balls are more likely to be at the border. We don't know if this statistic has a closed functional form, so we generated many p-value distributions for the random case and plotted the histogram of $D$.

Doing this for the data, we observe (orange histogram below) that there are only positive values of $D$ and that its histogram does not overlap with the value $D=0$. So: (1) we can reject the random case, and (2) the positivity of $D$ indicates that red balls are more likely to be at the border than in the random case.

[image]

## QUESTIONS

(1) Our choice of performing the test on the scale of the entity was motivated by the availability of an exact (hypergeometric) model for the random (uncorrelated) case. The disadvantage of this choice is that we end up with many p-values, which need interpretation. We managed to do this but the approach feels quite unconventional. Are there any problems with our approach and is there a stronger case for pooling all the borders and interiors together, despite the possibility that this might introduce spurious correlations? Or is there perhaps a more standard method for this?

(2) It is also not immediately clear how we should calculate the aggregate effect size. Is this simply the average of the difference in proportions (proportion red at the border minus proportion red in the interior), or should the average be weighted by something related to the sample sizes in each entity?

Comment: You could just test the null hypothesis that the probability of having $p\le 0.05$ is 0.05 against the alternative that it is bigger. Simple Binomial test. Not necessarily the best thing possible in terms of power, but if the situation is crystal clear and you just want something methodologically correct to "claim significance", that should do. (If there are no reasons against this that I have missed, I can make this an answer.)

Comment: Well, one reason against it is this: Any test is invalid that is chosen based on the data on which you want to claim significance, because this means you can play around until *something* gives you significance, which is potentially meaningless. But this is not a specific problem with the test I suggested, rather with describing the data and asking what will bring you significance in general. If you try out my (or any) idea on new data, it should work.

Comment: I realised from your answer that my post wasn't clear enough. There are two p-value distributions we want to compare. I updated my post and tried to focus on the relevant parts. Let me know if more clarification is required.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't put all of your data in a single (binomial) model, with effects for red/green, border/interior, and entity -- the latter possibly random?

Comment: @PBulls, you mean doing the same test for proportions on the pooled data, summing all the borders/interiors for all entities, right? What exactly do you mean with a random variable for an entity? We thought that pooling everything together may result in having correlations in the aggregate data that are not present in the entity-scale data, something like a reverse Simpson's paradox.

Comment: Yes, if you just were to pool all data you would assume independence/the same outcome regardless of entity. Hence adding that as an effect in the model, either fixed or random. Your abstraction has made it a bit vague what the exact clustering in the data is (what is an 'entity' exactly?), but my guess is a random effect is appropriate & this would address correlation within entity.

Comment: OK, if I get this right, you are arguing I could use a multilevel model in which both the variation between and within entities are analysed?

Comment: I believe that given that the "random" p-values are conservative, i.e., the probability to reject at 5% is actually lower than 5% and that this is theoretically valid, my original idea in the first comment can still be applied. Under $H_0$ you expect $\le 0.05$ probability of rejection at 5% level, so if you see significantly more, the overall $H_0$ can be rejected. I don't think it's wrong what you are doing, but it's so much more complicated, harder to explain and harder to argue.

Comment: Note that there is no unified definition of "effect size" over all kinds of problems, so there won't be a standard way to define this in your situation. I also think that what makes sense may somehow depend on some more understanding of the role of within-entity variation vs. between-entity variation for the specific data you have. You could average entity-wise differences and not call it "effect size" but just say what it is and interpret it at face value. Whether this is the best thing to do I don't know, but if you do something intuitive and transparent, it can't be all too wrong.